# PDO object not in scope of a function

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

OK, I see some similar questions to mine, but their examples all use PHP classes...mine does not. Maybe that's the problem? I shouldn't need classes because my site is exceedingly simple at this point in time.

Anyway, I'm trying to use PDO to connect to a MySQL db. I connect to the db fine in a file called `config.php`, and include this file in `index.php` with `require_once()`.

I can successfully query the db from another file called `process.php`, but the problem is within a function within that file; it seems my DBO object is out of scope within that function.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**index.php**

```
require_once('./lib/config.php');
```

**config.php**

```
// tested and connects fine    
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $username, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
...
// can call $pdo fine in this file outside of functions
...

function authenticate($u, $p) {
    // can't call $pdo in here, error says $pdo is non-object
    $que = $pdo->query('select user_id, user_pass from users where user_name = \'' . $u . '\' limit 1');
    ...
}

?>
```

By the way, I'm using PDO because I was having similar trouble with `mysqli`, and am trying to get away from `mysql`, which is apparently depreciated and discouraged.

EDIT: I should have clarified first based on the number of responses I got on this matter: I did try to **pass $pdo in as a param to the function**, with no luck or change in the error message.

SOLUTION: OK, apparently the problem was that I needed to add `require_once('config.php')` in my **process.php** file as well. Not sure why (wouldn't it already be included when **index.php** was run first?). Then I was able to successfully pass `$pdo` in as a param to my function, and voila.

Comment: In your authenticate function, `$pdo` is out of scope. Pass it in as a parameter, or declare it as a global.

Comment: If you really must, declare it as `global $pdo;` inside your function. You better pass it or put `authenticate` in a class though.

Comment: Use proper classes and objects and then use dependency injection.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [pretty basic PHP stuff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Variables inside functions are local variables unless you use the `global` keyword to load them. I suppose you want this:

```
function authenticate(PDO $pdo, $u, $p) {
    $que = $pdo->query('select user_id, user_pass from users where user_name = \'' . $u . '\' limit 1');
    //...
}
```

**Edit:** If PHP claims that `$pdo` is not an object, it's not an object, so it doesn't really matter how it's passed to the function. Inspect the variable right before you call `authenticate()`:

```
var_dump($pdo);
```

Without the relevant code there's no way to say why. (Assuming it's true that `new PDO` succeeds.)

Comment: Yes. I would echo the approach here of passing the PDO object to the function (this is know as dependency injection). It is much cleaner than using `global` in the function.

Comment: Yes, please see my edits, sorry. Should have clarified first that passing in `$pdo` as a param was the first thing I tried, without success.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, see my solution edit. When the config.php file was required (again) locally, the parameter passing worked just as you said. Not sure why I had to require config.php twice, but whatever.

Comment: But, is `process.php` included from `index.php`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: No, `process.php` is called via jQuery AJAX. But `index.php` is run before anything, so I figured the `require_once()` in there would suffice for the rest of the site onward.

Comment: @praguian - That's not how HTTP works. HTTP is stateless. Each request is independent.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - You're right of course. I must be rusty. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the PDO object as a parameter to the `authenticate()` function:

```
function authenticate(PDO $pdo, $u, $p) {
    // ..as in the question..
}
```

Oh and you should be using a place holder for that username in the query, not string concatenation which is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks. The query you see is dummied down for this purpose, not the actual query I'll run in my code :). Don't worry, everything will be properly escaped at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

because `$pdo` has been declared outside of the function `authenticate` it isn't available inside it. You need to either pass $pdo in

```
function authenticate($u, $p, $pdo) {
    $que = $pdo->query('...');
}
```

or declare it as global inside the function to be able to access it

```
function authenticate($u, $p) {
    global $pdo;
    $que = $pdo->query('...');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit. I did try passing `$pdo` in as a param originally, without luck.

Comment: You can't just do `function authenticate($u, $p, $pdo)` to pass it in you have to do it when calling the function as well. `$result = authenticate($u, $p, $pdo)`

Comment: I know, I did both pieces. See my new edit. The problem was the lack of another `require_once()` call to get the db connection in the first place. Then the param passing worked.